# How to extract from_dict to pandas dataframe with varying array length?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dict, I need to convert to pandas dataframe, dict have arrays, if the arrays are of same length it is working fine, but different length array throwing valueError, second question is I need to access only few key value pairs from the dict

This case working, as expected I get two rows

```
my_dict = {
          "ColA" : "No",
          "ColB" : [
            {
              "ColB_a" : "2011-10-26T00:00:00Z",
              "ColB_b" : 8.3
            },
            {
              "ColB_a" : "2013-10-26T00:00:00Z",
              "ColB_b" : 5.3
            }
          ],
          "ColC" : "Graduate",
          "ColD" : [
            {
              "ColD_a" : 5436.0,
              "ColD_b" : "RD"
            },
            {
              "ColD_a" : 4658.0,
              "ColD_b" : "DV"
            }
          ],
          "ColE" : "Work"
        }

sa = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```

[image]

In this case ColB has only one value

```
my_dict = {
          "ColA" : "No",
          "ColB" : [
            {
              "ColB_a" : "2011-10-26T00:00:00Z",
              "ColB_b" : 8.3
            }
          ],
          "ColC" : "Graduate",
          "ColD" : [
            {
              "ColD_a" : 5436.0,
              "ColD_b" : "RD"
            },
            {
              "ColD_a" : 4658.0,
              "ColD_b" : "DV"
            }
          ],
          "ColE" : "Work"
        }

sa = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```

so this throws ValueError: arrays must all be same length, How this can be fixed?
expected output is

[image]

I can do

```
sa = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index').transpose()
```

But I have to melt and join again.
Second Question, if I need to choose only ColA, ColB from dict to create dataframe, How this to be done?

Answer (score 0):

for your second question, you could select a couple of columns from your dictionary using 'columns' parameter: For example:
`sa = pd.DataFrame(my_dict, columns = ['ColA', 'ColD'])`